# how to take input in a 2D char array using C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am getting weird results when I try to take input of a 2D **char** array for some reason. I have always taken integer 2D arrays in the past this way but somehow this method doesn't work for char arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char a[n][n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%c",a[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Excepted Input**:

3

a b c

d e f

g h i

**Expected Output**:

a b c

d e f

g h i

What happens:

3

a b c

d e f

(Input abruptly stops)

Output:

a b c

d

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "doesn't work" part? ***How*** doesn't it work? What is your input? What is your expected output? What is the actual output? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And also please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What do you input, what do you get, how does this differ from what you expected?

Comment: You probably want `scanf("%c\n",&a[i][j])` (extra `'\n'` at the end)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Better to add a space *before* the format. Otherwise the last `scanf` call will block until a non-space character is entered.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, right. I think it wouldn't need `\n` at all, just `" %c"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you insert the input like this:

1. a
2. whitespace
3. b
4. whitespace
5. c
6. enter...

then your program has too many `char`s in the input buffer. You want to read 9 `char` with `scanf("%c")` and indeed 9 `char`s enter the buffer, but they include things you don't want (whitespaces and newlines).

Fix: add whitespace before %c like this - `scanf(" %c",&a[i][j]);`. This would ignore any sort of whitespace between `char`s read (`'\n' '\t'" ' '`).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much :)